# Compliance Bushing for 2007 Honda Odyssey

Tags: honda, suspension

What are some part numbers that I can cross reference for the compliance bushings (control arm bushing) for a 2007 Honda Odyssey?

[image: Arm]

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about for these?

[image: From Rockauto.com]

If so, you are looking for [MOOG # RK620504](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=6385077&cc=1433851&jnid=403&jpid=0) for the lower right and MOOG # RK620505 for the lower left. If you don't want Moog parts, just use the numbers. You can order the parts online from rockauto.com or get them from your friendly neighborhood parts store.

There are also parts listed for upper and lower rear suspension bushings (DORMAN Part # 521800 right rear upper / DORMAN Part # 521799 left rear upper ... MOOG Part # RK642105 rear left forward / MOOG Part # RK642106 rear right forward).

Comment: Not the whole arm, just the bushing marked by the red arrow: ![arm](http://i.imgur.com/DF4ovIb.jpg)

Comment: @eddie_the_mutt ... You cannot replace just the bushing. It is molded into the arm.

Comment: While whomever down voted this answer is more than welcome to do so, an explanation as to *why* is appreciated and warranted.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the down vote either. It is not that you answer was wrong, I simply hadn't added enough detail yet.

Comment: So, these are different than most Honda control arms that familiar with? With what I am used to, you can chop / burn the old bushing out and press a new one in with a hydraulic press.

Comment: @eddie_the_mutt ... I guess you might be able to, but your guess is as good as mine where to get just the bushing. I've done it before with poly bushings, but not the rubber kind like you'd *normally* be using here.